# Sending a message on discord every 15 minutes

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot that sends a random message every 15 minutes. The bot loads up no issues but no messages send am I missing something?

```
import discord
import asyncio
import random
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

client = discord.Client()
token = 'xxx'

@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def background_loop():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while not client.is_closed:
        channel = client.get_channel(xxx)
        messages = ["Hello!", "How are you doing?", "Howdy!"]
        await channel.send(random.choice(messages))
background_loop.start()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to use `tasks`, you're using it a little bit wrong. Here is a documentation of how to use [`tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/). Also, there's nothing like `client.send_message`. You can just do `channel.send(message)`.

```py
@tasks.loop(minutes=15.0)
async def background_loop():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while not client.is_closed:
        channel = client.get_channel(id)
        messages = ["Hello!", "How are you doing?", "Howdy!"]
        await channel.send(random.choice(messages))
background_loop.start()
```

Comment: I edited the code from the original post to match what you sent me (except I changed minutes to seconds just so I could see it working. But it still does not do anything.

Comment: Can you remove `while not client.is_closed` and add a real channel id instead of `xxx`?

Comment: Perfect it works now. I do have a real channel ID on there just replaced it with xxx for this site.